# What is the best practice to call a DELETE restful method from a web page?

Tags: c#, restful-architecture, nancy

I am building a small Nancy webapp which would do CRUD operations on a table. It uses GET, POST and DELETE verbs. I want to have a link in the web page to call the delete method. Using a "anchor" tag would use the GET method, by default. I am not comfortable with changing the webservice to use GET verb to do delete operations as it would break RESTful concept. What is the best practice in such situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the GET verb for desctructive/state changing operations so using DELETE or POST is the way to go (DELETE is semantically correct in your case).

With javascript you can hook on the anchor click event and fire the request with the DELETE verb.

A small sample with Jquery's [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options):

```
<a href='/deleteAction/myId' class='deleteLink'>Delete me</a>

$('.deleteLink').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     url: $(this).attr('href'),
     type: 'DELETE',
     success: function(result) {        
  }});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, using ajax is the only way? Thanks again.

Comment: HTML forms only supports GET and POST. The other verbs like PUT, DELETE are supported by the implementations of XMLHttpRequest in all the major web browsers. So ajax is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `GET` verb for `DELETE`, `GET` is considered to be a safe operation and is not supposed to change your application's state.

You should use `DELETE` and can also use `POST` (because some firewalls do not allow `DELETE`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Asif. That is my concern. I want to have a "delete" link pointing to the "/element/{elementid}/delete" path, next to my data element. When pressed, this should call the path using the DELETE method. How can I get a normal html link to do "DELETE" operation?

Comment: You have to do it in Javascript, look at the nemesv answer.